# Posting HTML content to PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I'm posting HTML content via AJAX to PHP. During debugging process i see that ajax posts whole content from editor. But when i'm checking my db I see 40-50% of sent content. Filtering sent data with following function in php. My database field type is text with 0 length.

```
function html($data, $db)
{
$data = htmlentities($data);        
$data = $db->escape_string($data);
return $data;
}
```

No success. But when i'm trying to post standard text content (none-html) it posts whole content into db table. How to deal with that problem? Any suggestions?

**JS**

```
function postViaAjax(autosaveMode) {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var menu = $("#menu").val();
    var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    if (parentcheck == 0) {
        var parent = parentcheck;
    } else {
        var parent = $("#parent").val();
    }
    var content = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&title=' + title + '&menu=' + menu + '&parentcheck=' + parentcheck + '&id=' + id + '&parent=' + parent + '&content=' + content;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processor/dbadd.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status, xResponse) {
            var message = result.msg;
            var err = result.err;
            var now = new Date();
            if (message != null) {
                if (autosaveMode) {
                    $('#submit_btn').attr({
                        'value': 'Yadda saxlanıldı ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()
                    });
                } else {
                    $.notifyBar({
                        cls: "success",
                        html: message + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()
                    });
                }
            }
            if (err != null) {
                $.notifyBar({
                    cls: "error",
                    html: err
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Please post the javascript code which posts the data.

Comment: Maybe your db field has limited text size?

Comment: when i'm trying to post standard text content (none-html) it posts whole content into db table.

Comment: why are you running it through `htmlentities()` as well as escaping it for the DB?

Comment: getting output like this http://prntscr.com/3c8ht . From which functions data needs to be pass while insert and while output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely because you need to escape your "content" when you're posting it.

Try

```
content = encodeURIComponent(content)
```

or

```
content = encodeURI(content)
```

Before appending it to the dataString

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking about this the wrong way. The PHP script that you have the callback function on will receive all the data which you tell it to receive.

If you are using a library such as jQuery, you can set something up so its a bit like the following:

```
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourFile.php?'+formValues,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
    return false;
```

Then you will just have to have your php script pick up the data which is being sent. You can do that via POST or GET it is entirely up to you and depending on what you are doing.

I hope this helps get you started.

Comment: I now what's serialize, and my function does exactly same thing. I don't use serialize becauze I'm using CKeditor. `var content = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();` to get editor data